# Is $l^2 \subset l^3$?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

I have a feeling that it's true that $l^2 \subset l^3$. But I have no idea how to prove it. Basically I just need to prove that for every sequence $(x_n)$ that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {|x_n|^2}<\infty$$
then
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {|x_n|^3}<\infty$$.
But, still no Idea. Can you help me?

If it's true, can we make it general like:
$$l^p \subset l^{p+1}$$
for all $p\in\mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $\{x_n\}\in\ell^2$.  Then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {|x_n|^2}<\infty$.  Without loss of generality, suppose $|x_n|\leq1$ for all $n$ (otherwise multiply the sequence by an appropriate constant).  Then $|x_n|^3\leq|x_n|^2\leq1$ for all $n$, and the comparison test yields 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {|x_n|^3}\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {|x_n|^2}<\infty$$

and therefore $\{x_n\}\in\ell^3$.  Note that essentially the same proof can show that $\ell^p\subset\ell^q$ whenenver $1 \leq p<q<\infty$, and the case $q=\infty$ is trivial.

Comment: Thanks... actually I've been thinking same way as yours but I stuck because I worried that I can't say that $|x_n|\leq 1$ easily. Thank you very much.... ^^